# Attempting to create a dictionary through iteration and geocoding

Tags: swift, asynchronous, geocoding

I have a list of address on Parse that I am trying to put into a dictionary with the following format : `[CLLocation:PFObject]`, so basically I am geocoding each address from an array of PFObjects I have called `price` and storing the corresponding PFObject into my dictionary restaurantDict. Unfortunately when I try printing out my dictionary I get a bunch of empty cells. Is there an issues with sending geocode requests in a loop like this?

```
 for price in prices {
    var location:String = price.objectForKey("Address") as String
    geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
            if error != nil {
                println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if placemarks.count > 0 {
                var placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                var location = placemark.location
                var coordinateLocation:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude) as CLLocation
                self.restaurantDict[coordinateLocation] = price as PFObject
                print(i)
                i++
            }
})
```

Comment: I should not my original query which contains all the price objects is being returned just fine, my code is just totally skipping over this geocodeAddressString function.

Comment: You are trying to do asynchronous stuff synchronously.  Your `forin` loop has probably finished looping before you even get to the first `print` statement.

Comment: Thanks @nhgrif. Any ideas for how to get around this? Or an example I can read up on?

Comment: Use a function instead of forloop for async

Comment: @Arbitur Can you elaborate? I still need to loop through these values..

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods of doing this but the way I do it is by using a function as a "for-loop"

```
func loopArr(var arr: [AnyObject]) {
    asyncMethod() {
        doSomethingWithArr(arr.removeLast())
        if arr.count > 0 {
            self.loopArr(arr)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this gets all the geocoding to be completed but only after the rest of my app has run. Is there anyway I can wait until all geocoding results have been found?

Comment: You can simply check of its the last loop and then do studf

Comment: This idiom (say, "asynchronous loop") is asynchronous. That is, function `loopArr` is an _asynchronous_ function. Thus, it would deserve a completion handler or some other means to signal completion.  (Which would also answer @thankyouinadvance question in her/his first comment.)

Comment: Why would you 'need' a completion handler just do some sync stuff inside the async and once that sync stuff is done call loopArr again